# Jenkins deploy fails on Tomcat 7, java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/list

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

My Jenkins deploy fails with below exception, I installed the deploy plugin updated tomcat-users.xml with various users as below.

```
<user username="deployer" password="deployer" roles="manager-script"/>
<role rolename=”manager”/>
   <role rolename=”admin”/>
   <user username=”harpreet” password=”harpreet” `roles=”standard,manager,admin,manager-gui,manager-script” />`
```

Updated my jenkins Job Configure page with below informaion.

Deploy war/ear to a container WAR/EAR files - **/*.war
Context path    - Barclays_Tokenization

Containers  Tomcat 7.x
Manager user name   - harpreet (I tried deployer too earlier)
Manager password    - ••••••••

Tomcat URL  - http://localhost:8081

Not sure what is wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.
I am new to Java Development.
Any response is appreciated. Thanks

```
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Barclays_Tokenization\workspace\target\Barclays_Tokenization-V-0.0.1.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:193)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
    ... 16 more
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 2):

Check {catalina.base}/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml

It seems you have NO manager app

Answer (score 1):

did you check the webapps folder in tomcat, to make sure if it has manager(folder) app?
if Yes, please check, the user you are using to access manager app has manager-* roles assigned in tomcat-users.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that I made was that I had put the users and their roles after the tag .

Yes, silly mistake, but it took days to debug :(